# What's the simplest way to find someone's Facebook profile by their email address?

Tags: facebook, search

As the title says, is it possible to look up the Facebook profile which corresponds to a particular email address, if there is one? What's the simplest way to do so?

I know there is (or used to be) a feature where you could provide your email account login credentials and Facebook would read the email addresses in your contact list and show you any corresponding profiles. But there are plenty of privacy concerns inherent in that model, so I'd rather not do that (though if that is indeed the only way, I'd like to know). Besides, I'm just interested in searching for a single email address, not an entire list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As the title says, is it possible to look up the Facebook profile which corresponds to a particular email address, if there is one? What's the simplest way to do so?

Yeah, just enter the email address in to the search box. If that's known to facebook then it'll bring up that person.

[image]

Comment: Huh, I thought I tried that... guess not. It works!

Comment: but why doesn't it work for me